# php header redirects not working

Tags: php, session-variables, isset

So, I consolidated various php login files from [here](http://phpsense.com/2006/php-login-script/) into [one file](http://rg3k.com/dl/post.zip).
to consolidate it to one file, I append the url, and do different things based off of what is appended.

This works locally but not on my remote server.

Anyway...

At the top of my 'consolidated' file I have

```
session_start();
```

This is the only time I have a session_start(). The rest of my post.php code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['app1'])){
...do stuff
header("location:post.php?app2");
    exit();
}
if(isset($_GET['app2'])){
...do other stuff
header("location:post.php?app3");
    exit();
}
```

Locally, if I start at post.php?app1, it will go to post.php?app2 and work fine, but on the remote server it just gets stuck (no redirect). Does anyone know why?

Comment: I am not sure but may be because of space it causes problem try this `header("Location: post.php?app2");`. And as you coded it should be redirected to `app3` not to `app2`

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - Agree with you.

Comment: Are you sure the execution reaches the `header(...)` lines?

Comment: check your remote server php.ini settings

Comment: @blasteralfred i don't think it is an issue with the remote server settings - these were causing problems before i 'consolidated' but i changed them

Comment: @Mikhail Vladimirov I am not sure - do you know how to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe these happen because there was a code that provide an output before trying to redirect.
try add buffer function in your 'consolidated'file.

```
ob_start();
session_start();
```

Comment: add the ob_start(); at the top of the file?

Comment: Well I added the ob_start(); and it works now, thank you!! An easy fix I would have never been able to find.

I also moved my session_start(); up, because there was an include that was executed before it

BEFORE)
    include 'db';
    session_start();
AFTER)
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include 'db';

Comment: you can learn more about what is `ob_start` in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). glad that helping you

Comment: btw, you can +1 my answer if it helpful. it's helping me a lot, hehe